OAuth 2.0 User Authorization Code client/server layout
I am needing to send some REST API requests to Jira which allows a few authentication types, but OAuth2.0 is the most secure. 
I understand that you need to be hosting a callback URL so you can receive the code needed to finish the authentication flow. The question is, should I be doing this flow on the client side (a distributed program), or on the server side (the one that hosts the callback)? Either way, I would have to tell the client either the code OR the credentials that can be used to send requests. The next question is: How do I go about knowing when there is a code for the client on the server? I can poll the server, but that would be pretty inefficient, and ideally, I would want to use a cloud server, and not have to run the server off the machine itself, unless that is of course the standard. 
A little backstory on the client:
It will be used to create/modify tickets, that is it. It needs user input that can be parsed appropriately/safely then eventually sent to the ticket.\
On the other end despite everything else I have just said about OAuth2.0.
Would it be bad to retrieve an API token instead from a server, that way it is not hardcoded in? This is another one of Jiras methods for REST API authentication.
I have already tested the API token method, and it is of course the simplest, but I would like the appropriate answer given the scenario.
I am thinking OAuth2.0 is not appropriate because it is not a "user account" that needs to be making these API calls, but rather a service account that is dedicated for it.
